# Should I do any variable conversion?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, type-conversion

I made the below HTML+javascript program to give a specific formatted output,
It first extracts array values from "location" array and places them in "a" array,then for loop produces output in latitude and longitude format,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var location =[33.53625,-111.92674,33.51049,-111.96279,33.50161,-111.90374];
var a =[{lat:location[0] , lng: location[1]},{lat: location[2], lng: location[3]},{lat: location[4], lng: location[5]}];


var txt = "";
var n;
var h;
for (x in a) {
    n=2*parseInt(x);
    h=(2*parseInt(x))+1;
    txt += "{lat: "+location[n]+" , lng:"+location[h]+"},"+"\n";
}
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = String(txt);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I press the button the output is,

```
{lat: 33.53625 , lng:-111.92674}, {lat: 33.51049 , lng:-111.96279}, {lat: 33.50161 , lng:-111.90374},
```

Now,the above output is stored in **var txt**, So, I placed **"txt"** in the below google api program in triangleCoords,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Polygon</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

// This example creates a simple polygon representing the Bermuda Triangle.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     zoom: 12,
    center: {lat: 33.53625, lng: -111.92674},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });



 var location =[33.53625,-111.92674,33.51049,-111.96279,33.50161,-111.90374];
var a =[{lat:location[0] , lng: location[1]},{lat: location[2], lng: location[3]},{lat: location[4], lng: location[5]}];


var txt = "";
var n;
var h;
for (x in a) {
    n=2*parseInt(x);
    h=(2*parseInt(x))+1;
    txt += "{lat: "+location[n]+" , lng:"+location[h]+"},"+"\n";
}
    var triangleCoords = [
       txt
    ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35

  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but I am not getting polygon over map,but I am able to get polygon output if I just replace **txt** with its standalone output

```
var triangleCoords = [
   {lat: 33.53625 , lng:-111.92674}, {lat: 33.51049 , lng:-111.96279}, {lat: 33.50161 , lng:-111.90374},


];
```

Should I convert txt into some other format?or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to create an array of objects, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the string in the array means that you get the same result as:

```
var triangleCoords = [
   "{lat: 33.53625 , lng:-111.92674},\n {lat: 33.51049 , lng:-111.96279},\n {lat: 33.50161 , lng:-111.90374},\n"
];
```

That's not an array of objects, that's an array with a single string in it.

Put actual objects in the array instead of creating the string format of objects:

```
var triangleCoords = [];
for (x in a) {
  n = 2 * x;
  h = 2 * x + 1;
  triangleCoords.push({ lat: location[n], lng: location[h] });
}
```

However, the easiest way would be to use the array of objects that you already have created:

```
var triangleCoords = a;
```

Comment: Thanks so much,ya I can use trianglecoords array that created already but this is just an experimental program,In actual program I will be passing   n number of coordinates for p number of polygons,So the program will seperate coordinates for each polygon and produce its polygon based on number of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I could just post the few lines that you need to change, but you would be learning nothing but copy&paste.

Your problem here is that you don't know the basis of javascript, or even types basis.

Your `str` var is a `String`

```
typeof str; // "string"
```

Your desired return value to this is

```
typeof str; // "object" - You shouldn't even call it str, BTW
```

#### Let's start from scratch

The first thing you have is

```
var location = [33.53625,-111.92674,33.51049,-111.96279,33.50161,-111.90374];
```

Where `typeof location` returns `object`. So far, we're good.

Then we've got

```
var a =[{lat:location[0] , lng: location[1]},{lat: location[2], lng: location[3]},{lat: location[4], lng: location[5]}];
```

**Important: avoid using this kind of inexpressive var names.**

At this point, `typeof a` returns `object`

The structure of `a` is the following

```
[
    {
        "lat": xxxx,
        "lng": xxxx
    },
    {
        "lat": xxxx,
        "lng": xxxx
    },
    {
        "lat": xxxx,
        "lng": xxxx
    },
]
```

This is just what you need for your Google Maps purpose according to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PolygonOptions).

> paths: Type <Array LatLngLiteral>

So you can pass `a` to the Polygon constructor

```
// Construct the polygon.
var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: a,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.35
});

bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

---

#### Your mistake

After been that close, you started to mess up with strings. This two lines are **very** different

```
var str = '[{"lat":33.44545,"lng":-56.2333}]';
// typeof str -> "string"
var latLngs = [{"lat":33.44545,"lng":-56.2333}];
// typeof latLngs -> "object"
```

#### My recomendation

1) Always check that you're passing as argument the type that the function is expecting.

2) Become friends with the Javascript Console (press F12, and go to the **Console** tab)

3) Code until you learn, don't give up.